# unlock a video tutorial with permanent access when user connects nodejs mongodb Stripe

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I develop a login page for the user to log in

Once the user is logged in, I offer them a video tutorial payable with Stripe.

Once the payment is done, I wanted to save his payment in mongodb and allow him to access the video tutorial permanently when he connects

I managed to sign up and at the login it is in the database and the stripe code too

```
 const postCharge = (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
  
    stripe.customers.create({
      email: email,
      source:  source
    })
    .then(customer => stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 2500,
        currency: "usd",
        customer: customer.id
    }))
    
    .then(() => res.render('success'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect after the success page is rendered? Because in your code you have it after the payment is created to render the success view. So I am unsure of what you are asking? Also what template language are you using? Jade / HBS etc.

Comment: I use ejs. in fact when the payment is successful, I want the tutorial video to be available in a link that will be in a button called my lessons
ex: (udemy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem

```
const postCharge = async (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
   
   const email = req.body.stripeEmail
   const source = req.body.stripeToken
//    const name  =   req.body.name

   const savePayment = new Payment({
      nomid: req.user.id,
       email: email,
       source: source
   })

   /***  */
    savePayment.save((err, userPayment) =>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
    })
   /*** */
   
  
    stripe.customers.create({
      email: email,
      source:  source
    })
    .then(customer => stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 2500,
        currency: "usd",
        customer: customer.id,
    }))
    
    .then(() => res.render('success'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

    
}


const getPass = (req, res) =>{
    const nomId = req.user.id
   
    Payment.findOne({nomId}, function (err, docs) { 
        if (err)console.log(err) 
            res.render('tutorial')
       
    }); 

}
 
 

/******  I put that in a navbar ****/

   <button class="btn btn-info my-2 my-sm-0 m-3">
          <a class="nav-link text-white " href="/tutorial/<%= id  %>">
          Access aux Cours
          </a>
   </button>
```